# jQuery check if radio option is selected on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm checking when radio is checked remove disabled class else add disabled class, it's working fine. But on page load when radio is already checked, then it's not removing the disabled class. The radio is sometimes already selected as the page is being loaded dynamically using php.

**Html Code**

```
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" value="1" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" value="2" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner3" type="radio" value="3" />
<a href="#" id="situation" class="btn disabled">Next step</a>
```

**JS**

```
//Checkbox work situation
$('.selectOwner').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#situation").removeClass('disabled', this.checked);
    } else {
        $("#situation").addClass('disabled', this.checked);
    }
});
$("input[type=radio]").trigger('change');
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need the second parameter on the `addClass` and `removeClass` calls

Comment: Check with my answer, may be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

All of your logic is on the `change` event, who is not been triggered on the page load.

But you can trigger it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectOwner').trigger('change');
});
```

Or the shorter version:

```
$(function(){ $('.selectOwner').trigger('change'); })
```

**Suggestion:**

- If you are going to use any of the exemple above, I suggest you to remove then the part of `$("input[type=radio]").trigger('change');`, and let the event be triggered only on the page load;
- You don't need to pass a `bool` parameter to `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`, (*look on Snippet*)

**Working Snippet:**

```js
//Checkbox work situation
$('.selectOwner').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#situation").removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $("#situation").addClass('disabled');
    }
});

$(function(){ $('.selectOwner').trigger('change'); })
```

```css
/* CSS for better Visualization */
.disabled{
    background-color: gray;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" value="1" /> Orange
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" value="2" checked/> Apple
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner3" type="radio" value="3" /> Lemon

<br>
<br>
<span id="situation">Situation</span>
```

**Documentation:**

- [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 0):

Call your change function in Jquery Ready function

```js
//Checkbox work situation
$('.selectOwner').change(function(){
  if (this.checked){
    $("#situation").removeClass('disabled', this.checked);
  } else {
    $("#situation").addClass('disabled', this.checked);
  }   
});

$("input[type=radio]").trigger('change');
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selectOwner').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" value="1" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" value="2" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner3" type="radio" value="3" />
<a href="#" id="situation" class="btn disabled">Next step</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your logic is in a `change` event `function` so it's only triggered when your radio buttons change.

You've to create a `function` with your logic and call it when your radio `change` and when your document is `ready`.

```js
function checkRadios(){
 var checked = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
 console.log(checked);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  checkRadios();
});

$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
  checkRadios();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="first" />
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="second" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="third"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or add another test when document is ready :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        if($('.selectOwner').is(':checked')) {
           $("#situation").removeClass('disabled', this.checked);
        } else{
           $("#situation").addClass('disabled', this.checked);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

when page load then need to check any radio check or not so call a function   and when radio change then call function which also check that so in this case i make a function `checkedTest` which call onload and onchange time

```js
$('.selectOwner').change(function(){
        checkedTest(); // call this 
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        checkedTest(); // onload call this
    });

    function checkedTest() {
        // check that any radio is checked or not
        if($("input:radio[name='owner']").is(":checked")) {
            $("#situation").removeClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $("#situation").addClass('disabled');
        }

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" value="1" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" value="2" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner3" type="radio" value="3" />

<a href="#" id="situation" class="btn disabled">Next step</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function when the DOM is loaded using **`$(document).ready(function(){}`** and do some style when the link is disable for user point of view like below

**When option is not checked**

```js
function radioChange() {
  if ($("input:radio[name='owner']").is(":checked")) {
    $("#situation").removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#situation").addClass('disabled');
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  radioChange();
  $('.selectOwner').change(function() {
    radioChange();
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.btn.disabled {
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" value="1" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" value="2" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner3" type="radio" value="3" />
<a href="#" id="situation" class="btn">Next step</a>
```

**When option is already checked**

```js
function radioChange() {
  if ($("input:radio[name='owner']").is(":checked")) {
    $("#situation").removeClass('disabled');
  } else {
    $("#situation").addClass('disabled');
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  radioChange();
  $('.selectOwner').change(function() {
    radioChange();
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.btn.disabled {
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner1" type="radio" value="1" checked />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner2" type="radio" value="2" />
<input class="selectOwner" name="owner" id="owner3" type="radio" value="3" />
<a href="#" id="situation" class="btn">Next step</a>
```